# Encryption & Decryption of DataTable Object

Tags: c#, .net

I need some help in encrypting and decrypting a DataTable object.

Problem Scenario:

- Encrypting all the content of
  System.Data.DataTable object.

Required Features:

- To use Triple DES encryption logic
- Should convert all content or all cells for all columns and/or rows

Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thoughts would be to convert to XML ([DataSet.GetXML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.getxml.aspx)) and then do encryption on this XML Data. Have a look at the [System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx) Namespace ([TripleDES Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx)). Decrypting and converting your XML back to a DataSet is then trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that this is the best way to do this, but, it seems that would just be to iterate through the rows and columns (i.e. just use a double for loop, or foreach) and use this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.tripledes.aspx to do the Triple DES.
This code is NOT checked, but it should look like this:

```
 String fin = cell1.ToString();

//Create variables to help with read and write.
byte[] bin = new byte[100]; //This is intermediate storage for the encryption.
long rdlen = 0;              //This is the total number of bytes written.
long totlen = fin.Length;    //This is the total length of the input file.
int len;                     //This is the number of bytes to be written at a time.

TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();          
CryptoStream encStream = new CryptoStream(cell1, tdes.CreateEncryptor(tdesKey, tdesIV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

Console.WriteLine("Encrypting...");

//Read from the input file, then encrypt and write to the output file.
while(rdlen < totlen)
{
    len = fin.Read(bin, 0, 100);
    encStream.Write(bin, 0, len);
    rdlen = rdlen + len;
    Console.WriteLine("{0} bytes processed", rdlen);
}
```